# Google SPF fails with some IPs

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, gmail

GMail MX are

- ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM: 1
- ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM: 5
- ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM: 5
- ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM: 10
- ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM: 10

When checking for IPs for these names, each time your ask for a resolution you can hit differents IPs. Nothing strange here.

But some of them soft fail a standard SPF check for "gmail.com" domain.

How is this possible ?

[image: example]

Comment: That means that when checking for a SPF record, only the syntax can be verified, unless you actually send an email and test against the IP that was used for sending this email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is possible because they are by design independently configurable.** While not uncommon to use certain IP addresses and/or names for both sending and receiving mail, there is no necessity to do so.

If a certain address is found looking up mail exchanges for *receiving* mail, that alone does not tell you *anything* about whether that address will additionally be used for *sending* mail and should be designated as such in the relevant SPF record.

One thing worth double-checking, however, is any assumption that MX hosts are *never* sending mail. I often see both notifications ranging from worthless backscatter to somewhat-useful disposition notifications and out-of-office replies originating from hosts that their respective admin wrongly assumed as never sending mail.